# vs code is developed remotely through the bastion machine, and the connection fails

Tags: vscode-remote

```
[09:22:17.856] Starting forwarding server. local port 63062 -> socksPort 62866 -> remotePort 37395
[09:22:17.856] Forwarding server listening on port 63062
[09:22:17.856] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[09:22:17.857] [Forwarding server port 63062] Got connection 0
[09:22:17.857] Tunneled port 37395 to local port 63062
[09:22:17.857] Resolved "ssh-remote+dev_server" to "port 63062"
[09:22:17.859] ------




[09:22:17.861] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 37395: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
[09:22:17.865] [Forwarding server port 63062] Got connection 1
[09:22:17.867] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 37395: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
[09:22:17.879] > 
[09:22:17.880] > channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: 
[09:22:17.885] > 
> channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited:
[09:22:17.910] > 
[09:26:17.893] ------
```

When I connect the remote host through the bastion machine in vs code, vs code cannot connect to the remote host behind the bastion machine.

this is my config.

```
Host jump_server
  HostName xxx.xx.xx.xx
  User jump
  Port 60022

Host dev_server
  HostName xxx.xx.xx.xx
  User dev
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jump_server
```

I have tested a few things gleaned from the web but nothing has worked so far.
Could someone enlighten me on the reason for the problem or on a possible solution ? Thanks !